# venn diagram in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, venn-diagrams

Can you please help me to draw a venn diagram like the pic, below (and color if possible):
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think MathJax supports this. In any case it is off-topic here.

Comment: @user1 There's the common problem with 'I need this figure' questions: as it stands, there's little idea of what you've tried in TeX. Certainly TikZ and PSTricks (and others) offer the possibly to code input for such figures.

Comment: If I could try, i     didnt draw it with windows paint :)